# How can I get around-hook-like behavior for rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I have a number of rake tasks for which I would like to implement around-hook-like behavior. Specifically, I'm looking for a way to ensure that all of my Rake tasks execute in a particular (complicated, derived) `Time.use_zone` block.

For analogy, I have this in my `ApplicationController`:

```
around_filter :use_time_zone

def use_time_zone
  time_zone = non_trivial_derivation
  Time.use_zone(time_zone) { yield }
end
```

And now all of my controller actions will appropriately execute in the specified time zone. I would like some mechanism like this for Rake. I'd be willing to change or modify the dependency chain for my rake tasks, but I don't want to insert the actual time zone derivation code at the top of each rake task, out of concerns that that would lead to maintenance fragility. **I'm pretty sure that Rake dependencies hold the solution**--after all, Rake dependencies allow me to execute code in the context of my Rails application. But I can't figure out how to get that done for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a simple solution that doesn't require any external dependencies or gems such as [rake-hooks](https://github.com/guillermo/rake-hooks):

```
desc "rake around hook"
task :use_timezone, [:subtask] => :environment do |name, args|
  puts "using timezone"
  Rake::Task[args[:subtask]].invoke
  puts "end using timezone"
end

task :testing do
  puts "testing"
end
```

The idea is that you execute the main `use_timezone` task and pass in your actual task as an argument:

```
$ rake use_timezone[testing]
```

That outputs:

```
> using timezone
> testing
> end using timezone
```

For your case you can write it like this:

```
task :use_timezone, [:subtask] => :environment do |name, args|
  time_zone = non_trivial_derivation
  Time.use_zone(time_zone) { Rake::Task[args[:subtask]].invoke }
end
```

And use it like this:

```
$ rake use_timezone[your_task]
```

Hope that helps.